# Estimating the $(N-1)$- Hausdorff measure of $\Omega\cap \partial B(0,r)$ when $\lim_{r\to\infty} m(\Omega\cap B(0,r))/m(B(0,r))=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a open, unbounded and connected set ($N\ge 2$).

Let $m$ and $\mathcal{H}^{N-1}$ denote respectively, Lebesgue and $(N-1)$-Hausdorff measures. Suppose that $$\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{m(\Omega\cap B(0,r))}{m(B(0,r))}=0,$$

where $B(0,r)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^N:\ |x|<r\}$. Is it true that for all sequence $\delta_n\to 0$, $\delta_n>0$, $\delta_n>\delta_{n+1}$, there is a sequence $r_n\to \infty$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{H}^{N-1}(\Omega\cap\partial B(0,r_n))<\delta_n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that need not be the case. Consider

$$\Omega = \left\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^N : x_1 > 0, \sum_{i=2}^N x_i^2 < 1 \right\}.$$

Then you have

$$\frac{m(\Omega\cap B(0,r))}{m(B(0,r))} \sim \frac{\tau_{N-1}r}{\tau_Nr^N} \xrightarrow{r\to\infty} 0,\tag{1}$$

and

$$\mathcal{H}^{N-1}\left(\Omega \cap \partial B(0,r)\right) \to \tau_{N-1} > 0,\tag{2}$$

where $\tau_k$ is the $k$-dimensional measure of the $k$-dimensional unit ball. (If you normalise $\mathcal{H}^{N-1}$ differently than $\mathcal{H}^{N-1}([0,1]^{N-1}\times\{0\}) = 1$, you get a constant factor in $2$.)

Comment: Thank for you answer @Daniel. I cannot see why $(2)$ is true. For example, in the case $N=2$, it seem to me that $\mathcal{H}^{N-1}\left(\Omega \cap \partial B(0,r)\right)$ would be proportional to $\arctan{(1/r)}$. Maybe I am missgin something...

Comment: For $N = 2$, you get an arc of the circle of radius $r$ with width $2$. Precisely, $r(\cos\vartheta,\sin\vartheta)$ for $\lvert\vartheta\rvert \leqslant \arcsin \frac{1}{r}$. The length of that arc is $2r\arcsin \frac{1}{r} = 2 + O(r^{-2})$. Generally, you slice a cap of diameter $2$ off the $N-1$-dimensional sphere of radius $r$. As $r\to\infty$, the cap becomes flatter and "converges" to an $N-1$-dimensional ball of radius $1$.

Comment: Did you maybe mean to divide the $N-1$-dimensional measure by $r^{N-1}$?

Comment: No, you are right. I just forget to multiply by $r$. Thank you again.

Comment: What happens if I ask the following: Assuming the same condition, is it true that for almost every $\omega\in S(0,1)$, there exist $t_0>0$ such that, the set $r_{\omega,t_0}=\{t\omega, t\ge t_0\}$ satisfies $$\Omega\cap r_{\omega,t_0}=\emptyset?$$

Comment: I don't think so. It should be possible to spiral a tube in such a way that every ray intersects the tube for arbitrarily large radii. The projection of $\Omega\cap \partial B(0,r)$ onto the sphere of radius $1$ becomes arbitrarily small, but you need not even have that the measure of that projection converges to $0$. The set of radii where the projection has large measure however should be "small", mostly the measure of the projection becomes small.